# Help me. my boot time is more than 20s

Tags: boot, dmesg

i have a hp pavilion laptop with 2gb ram, intel i3 and 500gb hdd
boot time is taking too long(>20s). tried preload, e4rat, e4defrag etc but still no improvement
below is my dmesg output

```
-------------start of dmesg removed due to word limit--------------------
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.106596] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.374263] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM
[    0.846671] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    0.846720] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    1.257128] Freeing initrd memory: 25688K (ffff880034dc4000 - ffff8800366da000)
[    1.257138] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    1.257141] software IO TLB [mem 0x696c0000-0x6d6c0000] (64MB) mapped at [ffff8800696c0000-ffff88006d6bffff]
[    1.257205] Simple Boot Flag at 0x44 set to 0x1
[    1.257382] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x10, revision=0x28
[    1.257391] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x10, revision=0x28
[    1.257400] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x10, revision=0x28
[    1.257409] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x10, revision=0x28
[    1.257461] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    1.257465] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    1.257737] Initialise system trusted keyring
[    1.257785] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    1.257796] type=2000 audit(1429192879.232:1): initialized
[    1.284062] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    1.284935] zbud: loaded
[    1.285076] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    1.285119] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.285483] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[    1.285548] msgmni has been set to 3644
[    1.285598] Key type big_key registered
[    1.286008] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.286011] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.286038] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    1.286070] io scheduler noop registered
[    1.286073] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    1.286095] io scheduler cfq registered
[    1.286160] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: device [8086:0101] has invalid IRQ; check vendor BIOS
[    1.286274] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.286308] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: device [8086:1e10] has invalid IRQ; check vendor BIOS
[    1.286413] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: device [8086:1e12] has invalid IRQ; check vendor BIOS
[    1.286514] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: device [8086:1e14] has invalid IRQ; check vendor BIOS
[    1.286630] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    1.286643] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    1.286676] efifb: probing for efifb
[    1.287099] efifb: framebuffer at 0x90000000, mapped to 0xffffc90010400000, using 4160k, total 4160k
[    1.287103] efifb: mode is 1366x768x32, linelength=5504, pages=1
[    1.287104] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    1.287107] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    1.289654] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    1.292128] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    1.292157] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x21120
[    1.292158] intel_idle: v0.4 model 0x2A
[    1.292160] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[    1.292250] ipmi message handler version 39.2
[    1.292502] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    1.292749] ACPI: AC Adapter [ACAD] (off-line)
[    1.292845] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    1.293592] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    1.293637] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
[    1.293672] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    1.293720] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[    1.293750] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    1.294219] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    1.295132] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    1.295156] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (0 C)
[    1.295194] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    1.295287] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.297057] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    1.298234] brd: module loaded
[    1.298854] loop: module loaded
[    1.299155] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.299240] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    1.299261] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    1.299328] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    1.299391] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.300382] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.301485] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.302483] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.303498] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
[    1.308398] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.308415] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: irq 16, io mem 0xa3619000
[    1.318857] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.319877] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.320875] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.321870] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.322856] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-49-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.323844] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.324908] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.325873] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.326981] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.327925] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.328876] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    1.333716] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.333731] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 20, io mem 0xa3618000
[    1.342879] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.343824] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.344741] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.345652] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.346551] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-49-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.347466] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.348460] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.349364] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.350328] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.351238] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.352127] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.353011] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    1.353337] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    1.353341] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    1.355656] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.356635] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.357511] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.358483] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.358507] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.358566] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.359458] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.360344] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.361215] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-49-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.362099] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.363071] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.363953] hub 3-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.365106] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.365989] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.366920] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.367818] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.368715] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.369605] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-49-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.370495] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.371473] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.372363] hub 4-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.378969] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    1.387947] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.388847] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.389843] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.390890] rtc_cmos 00:05: RTC can wake from S4
[    1.391907] rtc_cmos 00:05: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    1.392823] rtc_cmos 00:05: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    1.393770] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.394721] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.27.0-ioctl (2013-10-30) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.395652] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.396572] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    1.404768] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    1.639204] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.799651] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.800605] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.801806] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.802908] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.915399] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.075887] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    2.076846] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.078042] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.079134] hub 2-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    2.151709] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.293441] TCP: cubic registered
[    2.294476] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.295580] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.295696] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2394.560 MHz
[    2.297494] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.298823] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.299416] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e3
[    2.299417] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.299418] usb 1-1.3: Product: BCM20702A0
[    2.299419] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[    2.299420] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: C01885FFF2EE
[    2.305262] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 6fca287c2573d09ca32c1980c0d763777a63d4f5'
[    2.306210] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.309573] Key type trusted registered
[    2.313794] Key type encrypted registered
[    2.314731] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    2.315665] IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    2.317050] regulator-dummy: disabling
[    2.318047]   Magic number: 11:634:30
[    2.319073] rtc_cmos 00:05: setting system clock to 2015-04-16 14:01:20 UTC (1429192880)
[    2.320627] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    2.321570] EDD information not available.
[    2.322553] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    2.323947] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1340K (ffffffff81d20000 - ffffffff81e6f000)
[    2.324907] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    2.327933] Freeing unused kernel memory: 796K (ffff880002739000 - ffff880002800000)
[    2.330561] Freeing unused kernel memory: 688K (ffff880002b54000 - ffff880002c00000)
[    2.351131] systemd-udevd[139]: starting version 204
[    2.372874] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    2.374809] rtsx_pci 0000:09:00.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.374846] rtsx_pci 0000:09:00.0: rtsx_pci_acquire_irq: pcr->msi_en = 1, pci->irq = 42
[    2.376100] usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.378304] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    2.378305] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    2.381666] r8169 0000:08:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    2.384110] r8169 0000:08:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.384308] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: RTL8105e at 0xffffc90000358000, 80:c1:6e:5d:f3:78, XID 00c00000 IRQ 43
[    2.386121] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    2.386248] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.399803] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x11 impl SATA mode
[    2.401350] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo pio slum part ems apst 
[    2.408447] scsi0 : ahci
[    2.410018] scsi1 : ahci
[    2.411483] scsi2 : ahci
[    2.413437] scsi3 : ahci
[    2.414510] scsi4 : ahci
[    2.415556] scsi5 : ahci
[    2.416866] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xa3617000 port 0xa3617100 irq 44
[    2.417794] ata2: DUMMY
[    2.418838] ata3: DUMMY
[    2.419739] ata4: DUMMY
[    2.420623] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xa3617000 port 0xa3617300 irq 44
[    2.421651] ata6: DUMMY
[    2.423409] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    2.424498] checking generic (90000000 410000) vs hw (90000000 10000000)
[    2.424500] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
[    2.425460] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    2.475970] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.475981] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    2.475986] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    2.476102] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    2.504059] [drm] Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307
[    2.504067] [drm] This can cause pipe underruns and display issues.
[    2.504070] [drm] Please upgrade your BIOS to fix this.
[    2.516614] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b2f4
[    2.516620] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    2.516623] usb 2-1.5: Product: HP Webcam-50
[    2.516625] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
[    2.516628] usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: 0x0001
[    2.521879] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.740181] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    2.748182] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    2.749573] ata5.00: ATAPI: hp      DVD-RAM UJ8B1, H.04, max UDMA/100
[    2.749692] ata1.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HTS547550A9E384, JE3OA50A, max UDMA/100
[    2.749696] ata1.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.751269] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.751504] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HTS54755 JE3O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.751648] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[    2.751650] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    2.751663] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.751702] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.751704] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.751732] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.759541] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.773983] scsi 4:0:0:0: CD-ROM            hp       DVD-RAM UJ8B1    H.04 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.789193] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.789194] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.789337] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.789420] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.807831]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    2.808181] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.121814] random: lvm urandom read with 66 bits of entropy available
[    3.204618] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    3.207574] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.5, id: 0x1e0b1, caps: 0xf00173/0x240000/0xa2400, board id: 2068, fw id: 1028260
[    3.207716] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.208723] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[    3.209892] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    3.217275] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    3.234539] acpi device:05: registered as cooling_device4
[    3.235625] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:03/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
[    3.237541] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    3.240769] acpi device:0e: registered as cooling_device5
[    3.241932] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input7
[    3.243190] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    3.247437] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    3.296745] Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.313559] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
[    3.841406] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[    8.798811] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.983791] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   10.202240] init: Failed to spawn ureadahead main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[   12.681988] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   12.782346] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   13.055280] systemd-udevd[395]: starting version 204
[   13.297936] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   13.344852] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[   13.517202] init: ureadahead-other main process (424) terminated with status 127
[   14.026644] init: ureadahead-other main process (434) terminated with status 127
[   14.124530] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   14.159049] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   14.947138] Initializing HPQ6001 module
[   14.947245] input: HP Wireless hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input8
[   14.970860] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   14.978006] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   14.978015] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   14.978021] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   14.978026] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO 2 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   14.978031] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.GPIO 3 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   14.978035] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   14.978037] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   14.978041] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO 2 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   14.978046] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.GPIO 3 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   14.978050] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   14.978052] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   15.271791] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <joerg.roedel@amd.com>
[   15.271797] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
[   15.272269] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   15.291567] hp_accel: laptop model unknown, using default axes configuration
[   15.299155] lis3lv02d: 8 bits 3DC sensor found
[   15.303743] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.346923] input: ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer as /devices/platform/lis3lv02d/input/input9
[   15.481627] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   15.481630] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   15.486177] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   15.491880] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 1706 MBytes.
[   15.492070] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 6840 count: 1
[   15.492302] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0x4000, size: 0x100
[   15.492310] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   15.492438] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   15.492458] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 13.35.5 [Mar 12 2014] with 1 minors
[   15.685315] kvm: disabled by bios
[   15.841610] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[   16.001042] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input10
[   16.037345] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   16.037367] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   16.037369] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.037378] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.037381] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.037387] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.069471] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   16.118778] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   16.173594] usb 1-1.3: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   16.173598] usb 1-1.3: Falling back to user helper
[   16.174159] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[   16.236072] mute LED gpio 10 polarity 0
[   16.236241] autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0xd/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   16.236244]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   16.236247]    hp_outs=1 (0xb/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   16.236248]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   16.236249]    inputs:
[   16.236252]      Internal Mic=0x11
[   16.236254]      Mic=0xc
[   16.241899] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   16.277920] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   16.278015] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   16.278094] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   16.515273] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   16.515278] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   16.515280] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.515281] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.515283] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.515284] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.515286] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.569454] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam-50 (04f2:b2f4)
[   16.576999] input: HP Webcam-50 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/input/input14
[   16.577080] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   16.577082] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   16.604280] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=584 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604290] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=584 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604296] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=584 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604305] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=583 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604313] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=583 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604320] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=583 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604621] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604628] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604633] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.604911] type=1400 audit(1429192894.771:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=584 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.059207] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (705) terminated with status 1
[   20.204542] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.204546] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.204555] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.218797] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.218810] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.218814] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: 20s boot time is not much, I think, especially with 2GB RAM... I have SSD drive, 4GB of RAM and Intel Core 2 Duo and my computer boots in 14s, so it's not bad...

Comment: I have 2.5 GB Ram and an old 2.1 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo. It requires at least 25 seconds here

Comment: 20 seconds isn't long at all. I'd be happy to get that with my installation. (i5, 3GB RAM, 320GB HD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way you seem to have omitted so far: GRUB profiling:

You can tell GRUB to create a profile containing which drivers needs to be loaded upon booting an OS instead of letting it search for it on every boot.

To do so, open the file `/etc/default/grub` with elevated privileges and change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="some other entries"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="some other entries profile"
```

Don't change any of the other entries. Save the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to notify GRUB of the config change. Afterwards reboot. **This reboot will be *slower* than usual**, as GRUB is now creating the profile.

When the system has booted, again edit above file and **remove** the `profile` entry, save and run `update-grub`, else all your boots  will be slower.

In future your system should start up faster. I've read of improvements of up to 10 seconds, but the actual result can vary and this extreme result is unlikely to be achievable with your hardware.

---

If you want to improve the speed further, you should upgrade your RAM and/or buy a faster HDD or SSD to install the OS on.

---

Btw: The preload daemon doesn't affect your boot time at all.

Comment: tried profile too :(

Comment: would like to know why there are sudden long delays like at [    8.983791] random: nonblocking pool is initialized